# scikit-learn svm import error

Tags: scikit-learn, enthought

I'm running  [Canopy](https://enthought.com/products/canopy/)  64-bit on a mac. After installing scikit-learn (using the package manager), I tried to import svm, and got the following error.

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/johnsaccount/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/liblinear.so, 2): Library not loaded: /System@rpath/libBLAS.dylib
```

Referenced from: /Users/johnsaccount/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/liblinear.so
  Reason: image not found

Any ideas on what might be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jsen,

My apologies for this error, it was my mistake when building that egg. The update should now be available and fix that error (the fixed version is 0.13.1-3, both 0.13.1-1 and 0.13.1-2 are broken on os x).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the report and sorry for the inconvenience.
I can reproduce this, apparently due to a build error on OSX (it works ok on Windows). We'll let you know when it is fixed.

Comment: LinearSVC not working as well. I thought it was just my install. Hurrah.